# No input field for Apple ID Verification Code

Tags: ios, apple-id, game-center

I have an older iPad Mini and when I try and use a game iOS Game Center asks for my password, which I enter, and is accepted. Then it asks to type in the Apple ID Verification Code, although there is nowhere to type it in.

[image: 2]

**EDIT**: Thanks to fsb's suggestion the verification code was accepted by typing it directly after the password into the Game Center login password field. I'm shocked Apple would expect anyone to know to do this without prior knowledge!

Comment: I am offended that Game Center even exists, but I wouldn't downvote someone for pointing out a rather stupid programming error in it.  :-)

Comment: I read on one of the Apple discussion threads that you can type the code into the password field, right after your password and without using any spaces.  Some posters there say it works.  I don't use Game Center but I'm assuming there's an Apple login on there somewhere.

Comment: The error message given (shown in the screenshot in the question) explains precisely how it works: entering ‘your password followed by the verification code’. I must be missing something with regard to what prior knowledge you mention is required to complete this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

*Late Edit:*
Due to more than one person being confused by the term 'followed by' & just to be clear…

First you must close the dialog telling you to do this, to get back to the password entry field.
Then, if your password is `pa55word` and your verification code is `123456`, then in the password field you must enter `pa55word123456` all in one string at one time.

---

According to [this Apple Support page](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204915?cid=tw_sc_pub_all_twofactorauthentication), the issue is **two-factor authentication with older devices/iOS**.

> ## What if I use two-factor authentication on a device running older software?
>
> If you use two-factor authentication with devices running older OS versions, you might be asked to add your six-digit verification code to the end of your password when signing in.

> [Get your verification code](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204974) from a trusted device running iOS 9 and later or OS X El Capitan and later, or have it sent to your trusted phone number. Then type your password followed by the six-digit verification code directly into the password field without any spaces between the password and the verification code.