# Why isn't my iPad Retina iCloud Drive login verification code not showing up on my iPhone or Mac?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, icloud, apple-id

I'm running an iPad retina, and trying to login to the iCloud Drive in the Settings App.

It is logged into the App store, and iCloud sync for the Notes app.

I also have an iPhone 6S and a Macbook Pro Retina. Normally the [2FA verification code](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT204915) (please enter this iCloud passcode) notifications show up on the other devices when doing iCloud related operations. (Turn on [iCloud backups](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT203977) etc).

When I try and login to iCloud Drive on my iPad, it asks me to login to iCloud with my password, and then pops up a 2FA verification code entry screen. But the code to enter doesn't come up on my other two devices.

My question is: **Why isn't my iPad Retina Cloud Drive login 2FA verification code not showing up on my iPhone or Mac?**

Edit: 2FA is enabled on the other two devices. That's how the 2FA notifications mentioned above pop up on the other two devices for other iCloud operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is 2FA enabled on your iPhone and Macbook? If it's only showing up on your iPad then that could mean 2FA is only enabled on your iPad.

Comment: Thanks @Anthony that's helpful. I've updated the question

Comment: Check and make sure all your devices are verified. You seem to have Find My iPhone enabled across the board, so this would be the next step.

Comment: Thanks @Anthony that was helpful. I'll put in more detail below.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out you can trigger a 2FA [verification](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT204974) code by going to:

iOS10: Settings > iCloud > Password and Security > Get Verification Code

iOS9: Settings > iCloud > [Your name at the top] > Password and Security > Get Verification Code

Now the challenge here is that the original iPad Retina [was](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7674401?start=0&tstart=0) [limited](http://appleinsider.com/articles/16/06/13/apples-ios-10-restricted-to-devices-with-a6-soc-or-newer) to iOS9.

The other challenge is that the iPad retina running iOS 9 appears to have a 4-character 2FA - whereas my other devices are generating 6-character verification codes. I'll try and solve that somewhere else.

There appears to be a [trick](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/267005/753) to get the verification code sent by SMS.

---

Edit - it turns out it was asking me for the login passcode, not the iCloud verification passcode. Going to give the tick to the other answer to thank them for helping out.